# Conflicting Functions

Tags: javascript, events

The nice people here recently helped me with some JavaScript which is posted below. However, it appears to be conflicting with another function that already exists on the site. Since I am a back-end programmer and know little of JavaScript, does anyone know how to resolve the conflict?

```
function showhide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
        var showElement = true;
        if (divid.style.display === 'block') {
            showElement = false;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (showElement) {
            divid.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code above is conflicting with the following, which is a reload icon for a CAPTCHA. There are no errors but the refresh does not do anything as long as the other code is there. Note that the code above is included site-wide and used on several other pages while the code below is used on only one of them.

```
<img src="/common/quickcaptcha/imagebuilder.php" border="1" id="verification">
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('verification').src='/common/quickcaptcha/imagebuilder.php?img=' + Math.random(); return false">
  <img src="/common/images/refreshicon.gif" width="22" height="22" border="0" title="Refresh Security Code">
</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

When you setup event listeners with that syntax (`.on{event} = ...`), you are overwriting any previously set listener for that event. For example:

```js
window.onload = function(){ console.log("A"); }; // Won't be executed
window.onload = function(){ console.log("B"); };
```

Instead, you should add an event listener, without impacting others:

```js
// Both of these will be executed
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ console.log("A"); });
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ console.log("B"); });
```

Comment: Caution using addEventListener, for browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener

Comment: True, I often forget about IE8 and below... I tend to ignore these old browsers, since Windows XP has stopped being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same logic for all events:

```js
//function that already exists
window.onload = function () {
    console.log("A");
}

//method to add multiple functions at "event" on a element (windows is default)
var addOn = function (event, func, element) {
    if (!element) {
        element = window;
    }

    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, func);
    }
    else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
    }
    else {
        var onevent = element['on' + event];

        element['on' + event] = function () {
            if (onevent) {
                onevent();
            }

            func();
        }
    }
}

//closure
var addOnLoad = function (func, element) {
    addOn('load', func, element);
}

//adding more new functions at onload
addOnLoad(function () {
    console.log("B");
});

addOnLoad(function () {
    console.log("C");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <img src="http://www.web1marketing.com/resources/tools/quickcaptcha/imagebuilder.php" border="1" id="verification" />

    <br />

    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('verification').src = 'http://www.web1marketing.com/resources/tools/quickcaptcha/imagebuilder.php?img=' + Math.random(); ">
        <img src="http://kinneygroup.com/wp-content/themes/Kinney-new/images/loading_arrows.gif" width="22" height="22" border="0" title="Refresh Security Code" />
    </a>


    <div class="hide" style="display: none;">element hidden</div>

    <script>
        //method to add multiple functions at "event" on a element (windows is default)
        var addOn = function (event, func, element) {
            if (!element) {
                element = window;
            }

            if (element.addEventListener) {
                element.addEventListener(event, func);
            }
            else if (element.attachEvent) {
                element.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
            }
            else {
                var onevent = element['on' + event];

                element['on' + event] = function () {
                    if (onevent) {
                        onevent();
                    }

                    func();
                }
            }
        }

        //closure
        var addOnLoad = function (func, element) {
            addOn('load', func, element);
        }

        //closure
        var addOnClick = function (func, element) {
            addOn('click', func, element);
        }


        function showhide(obj, divs) {
            var showFlag = true;

            if (obj.style.display === 'block') {
                showFlag = false;
            }
            for (let i = 0, max = divs.length; i < max; i++) {
                divs[i].style.display = 'none';
            }

            if (showFlag) {
                obj.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        addOnLoad(function () {
            var d = document;
            var anchors = d.getElementsByTagName("a");
            var divs = d.getElementsByClassName("hide");

            for (let i = 0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
                addOnClick(function () {
                    let e = divs[i];
                    showhide(e, divs);
                }, anchors[i]);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all! I'll give these ideas a try. Just to clarify, the existing function is not more than I showed - that is, it is an in-line call to a built-in JavaScript function while the other is a separate function.

Comment: I tried to apply this but not sure of the exact syntax especially in the inline function.

Comment: It's all posted in my original question. That's all there is related to this issue as the rest is PHP with database calls, other HTML form fields etc.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. addOnLoad(function() {
   var d = document;
   var anchors = d.getElementsByTagName("a");
   var divs = d.getElementsByClassName("hide");

   for (let i=0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
        anchors[i].onclick = function() {
              let e = divs[i];
              showhide( e,divs );
        };
    }
});

no?

Comment: How would I apply these ideas to the in-line code? <img src="/common/quickcaptcha/imagebuilder.php" border="1" id="verification">
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('verification').src='/common/quickcaptcha/imagebuilder.php?img=' + Math.random(); return false">
  <img src="/common/images/refreshicon.gif" width="22" height="22" border="0" title="Refresh Security Code">
</a>

Comment: Thank you. The refreshing of the image is working but not the visibility/hide feature, which is actually on a different and unrelated page than the form with the refresh as the JavaScript is being included site-wide in an external file. However, I'm apparently making too many comments so I'd best stop here and not get into trouble!

Comment: if you link me an url with no working case I can say you how fix it

Comment: I really appreciate the offer but unfortunately it's not yet live.